# Disabling stage transitions in AWS CodePipeline using Java CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-cdk

Looking through the cloudformation docs, there should be a way to disable a transition to an action.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codepipeline-pipeline.html#cfn-codepipeline-pipeline-disableinboundstagetransitions

Tried looking for the Java CDK counter part and found this.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/java/software/amazon/awscdk/services/codepipeline/CfnPipeline.StageTransitionProperty.html

However, I can't find a way to link it to a Pipeline.

Is this the right property class? If yes how do I link it to a Pipeline instance?

Answer (score 3):

CDK project has an answer for this - https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1649

Usage for CfnPipeline provided as

```js
const cfnPipeline = pipeline.node.findChild('Resource') as codepipeline.CfnPipeline
cfnPipeline.propertyOverrides.disableInboundStageTransitions = [{
    reason: 'Pipeline is triggered by schedule not source changes',
    stageName: 'Source'
}]
```

For python I was able to implement with the following

```
cfn_pipeline = pipeline.node.find_child('Resource')
cfn_pipeline.add_property_override(
    property_path='DisableInboundStageTransitions',
    value=[{
        'Reason': 'Pipeline is triggered by schedule not source changes',
        'StageName': 'Source'
    }]
)
```

You may consider using the `S3Trigger.NONE` enumeration on your **S3SourceAction** *trigger* parameter.